# How can I reset my commits while keeping my assume-unchanged files in git?

Tags: git, git-assume-unchanged

I have quite many files that I set as

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

In some cases my branch is messed up and diverged with origin/master. Let's say

```
and have 4 and 8 different commits each, respectively.
```

So I want to revert all my commits and keep update to origin/master while keeps my assume-unchanged files not being flushed.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `--assume-unchanged`, you can try `--skip-worktree` with `git update-index`.

A file with the flag `git update-index --skip-worktree` should resist a `git reset` (which would unstage from the index any added changes)

You can see a [full analysis of the differences between `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309).

> It looks like `--skip-worktree` is trying very hard to preserve your local data. But it doesn’t prevent you to get upstream changes if it is safe. Plus git doesn’t reset the flag on `pull`.
>   But ignoring the '`reset --hard`' command could become a nasty surprise for a developer.